# Script is not working jQuery scrollbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have used jQuery Scrollbox. its working good in local but its not working in production.

[image]

Here is my code jQuery

```
$(function () {
$('#demo').scrollbox({
linear: false, // Scroll method
startDelay: 2, // Start delay (in seconds)
delay: 2, // Delay after each scroll event (in seconds)
step: 5,// Distance of each single step (in pixels)
speed: 32, // Delay after each single step (in milliseconds)
switchItems: 1, // Items to switch after each scroll event
direction: 'scrollLeft',
distance: 'auto',
autoPlay: true,
onMouseOverPause: true,
paused: false,
queue: null
});

});

$(function () {
$('#demo1').scrollbox({
linear: false, // Scroll method
startDelay: 3, // Start delay (in seconds)
delay: 2, // Delay after each scroll event (in seconds)
step: 5,// Distance of each single step (in pixels)
speed: 32, // Delay after each single step (in milliseconds)
switchItems: 1, // Items to switch after each scroll event
direction: 'scrollLeft',
distance: 'auto',
autoPlay: true,
onMouseOverPause: true,
paused: false,
queue: null
});
});
```

Its totally stuck. How to fix this ?

Comment: Check console error messages when accessing on live environment.

Comment: Its working fine..no errors

Comment: I've checked the link you provided and see the console for error messages. It seems that there are no jquery references. Double check your jquery libraries.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: i have checked your link there is an error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function . try to remove this error

Comment: `ncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function feature.php:1425`

Comment: okay let me check again guys

Comment: you need to pass "$" as an argument on line 1425 from jQuery(document).ready(function(){   ... to  jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... just like you did above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is on your Script. It seems you have add following line:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('.page_of_paginationpagination_count_ba').appendTo('#owner_block_submenu_tree');
    });
</script>
```

You need **to ADD** a `$` as parameter in the function:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.page_of_paginationpagination_count_ba').appendTo('#owner_block_submenu_tree');
    });
</script>
```

Otherwise the browser dont knowing what `$` is - `$` is jQuery but you dont has defined is as the functions-parameter. Add these or use `jQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)`:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.page_of_paginationpagination_count_ba').appendTo('#owner_block_submenu_tree');
    });
</script>
```